# Why is `git submodules add` storing the GIT information in the parent .git?

Tags: git, repository, git-submodules, checkout

Doing `git submodule add` is just creating a ".git" file that points to a parent GIT folder containing the data. Example:

[image]

Why are submodules store in the parent and how can I prevent GIT from doing this? I want to keep a consistent structure like other modules I have, in which each project has their own ".git" folder sitting next to the where the project data is stored.

Comment: Why did you think something else would happen, and why would that matter?

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Submodules store their git data in the top project's git directory by design. Could you clarify why that's a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning submodules worked the way you described. But later Git developers decided to change to the current way of using `.git` file (named gitlink) and push `.git/` directory under superproject's `.git/modules/`. To fix existing repositories they created [`git submodule absorbgitdirs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-absorbgitdirs). So you can see they do all their best to do things the current way and there is no way to return to the original way of storing `.git/` directory in the submodules. You can move it back manually and fix `.git/config`. This is how I managed to do this for one submodule:

```bash
#! /bin/sh
set -e

# To the top-level directory of the current submodule
cd "`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`"

unset GIT_DIR

# If .git/ subdirectory is already here
test -d .git && exit 0

if ! test -f .git; then
    echo "Error: Cannot find gitlink, aborting" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Fix core.worktree now
git config --unset core.worktree

read _gitdir gitpath < .git
unset _gitdir
rm .git
exec mv "$gitpath" .git
```

I failed to run it from `git submodule foreach --recursive` because the command runs from top to bottom while my scripts can only be run from bottom to top (it doesn't fix children's `.git` links).

*Upd*. This is recursive variant:

```bash
#! /bin/sh
# The script cannot be run with `git submodule foreach --recursive`
# because the command runs recursively from top to bottom
# while the command is required to be run from bottom to top
# because it doesn't fix childrens' gitlinks.
# So the script runs recursion itself;
# it can be run with `git submodule foreach` without `--recursive`.
set -e

START_DIR="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname \"$0\"`"
PROG_DIR="`pwd`"
cd "$START_DIR"

# To the top-level directory of the current submodule or the superproject
cd "`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`"

unset GIT_DIR

# If .git/ subdirectory is already here
test -d .git && exit 0

if ! test -f .git; then
    echo "Error: Cannot find gitlink, aborting" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if test -f .gitmodules; then
    git submodule foreach "$PROG_DIR"/"`basename \"$0\"`"
fi

# Fix core.worktree now
git config --unset core.worktree

read _gitdir gitpath < .git
unset _gitdir
rm .git
exec mv "$gitpath" .git
```